# Identifiable class's id generation by multiple properties but too complex, How can I solve the problem?

Tags: swift, identifiable

I have to compare a lot of objects.
In order to improve speed, I want to make 'id' like the below code.
Unfortunately, Swift compiler can't process this code.
How can I fix it?

struct OBJ: Identifiable {
var i1: UInt
var i2: UInt
var i3: UInt
var i4: UInt
var i5: UInt
var i6: UInt
var i7: UInt
var i8: UInt
var i9: UInt
var i10: UInt
var i11: UInt
var i12: UInt

```
var id: UInt32 {
    ((i1 << 55) + (i2 << 50)) +
    ((i3 << 45) + (i4 << 40))) +
    (((i5 << 35) + (i6 << 30)) +
    ((i7 << 25) + (i8 << 20))) +
    (((i9 << 15) + (i10 << 10)) +
     ((i11 << 5) + i12
}
```

I want to make 'id' as UInt by multiple properties.
I expected that Swift make a Uint value for 'id' but it failed.

Comment: All the variables are `UInt`s, yet `id` is a `UInt32`? You need to convert.

Comment: Also the bit-shifting you are doing suggests that `id` should probably be `UInt` as well...